# Cannot connect to local webserver

Tags: networking, command-line, telnet

I can no longer connect to my local webserver With telnet. I get the message: "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host", it used to work perfectly and i have not made any changes to either the firewall or the router, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a host name or IP address?  Why telnet, not ssh?

Comment: Using IP, using telnet because it's on my home network and i'm more accustomed to it.

Comment: show `traceroute <ip>` and `route print`

Comment: "No route to host" means, obviously, routing problem - you have to detect is it on your side or now

Comment: traceroute gives this result: "sergei@sergei-MS-7253:~$ traceroute 192.168.0.13
traceroute to 192.168.0.13 (192.168.0.13), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  sergei-MS-7253.local (192.168.0.12)  3002.874 ms !H  3002.867 ms !H  3002.859 ms !H"... seems fine right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple, when my friend connected his iphone to the wifi while the server was down, keeping it connected while the server was starting up, the iphone "stole" the IP and forced the server to another IP.